# BizTalk error "Error: 1 (Field level error) Position in Field: 2 Data Value: 0.0000"

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I am getting the following error "Error: 1 (Field level error) SegmentID: MOA Position in TS: 13 Data Element ID: C51602 Position in Segment: 2 Position in Field: 2 Data Value: 0.0000"

I tried using the option in agreement tab allowing Leading Zeros (see below)

[image]

Any other things I could try and see. I am really stuck here.

Comment: You need to set the trailing zeros option as well as per https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/09d30214-484e-4650-a654-efb30b9ed105/edi-error-for-data-value?forum=biztalkgeneral

Comment: I have done that (isn't it the same as above screenshot?).. the above screenshot is from Validation Section.

Answer (score 1):

To be clear about this, your trading partner is technically sending you invalid EDI.  The guidance is specifically that non-significant digits be suppressed so "0.0000" is out of compliance.

So, the correct way to resolve this is to contact your trading partner and have them correct their output.

If they are unable or unwilling to do this, then yes, you have to disable this rule in the Agreement.

Note, to be sure you're using the correct Agreement, you should disable the Fallback Settings.

Comment: The thing is when I pass the same invoice EDI file through a different supplier, it reaches without errors. Only for the current supplier, it shows an error. Calling the supplier and telling them to change the 0.0000 values would be my last option. Could you elaborate more on the Fallback settings for agreement?

Comment: Right click on Parties and select Fallback Settings.  You disable them from there.

Comment: I disabled the X12 Fallback settings from the agreement, then passed the EDI file, but getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by going to EDI Fallback settings and in Validation allowing Leading and Trailing zeroes policy to be **Allowed**.

There are 2 type of settings: EDI Fallback and X12 Fallback settings. So we need to enable the option in both of them.